# How do you insert a docx.document.Document object into a zip file object in python?

Tags: python

I create word documents on the fly and I would like to insert them in the same zip folder object that will be downloadable in a web page but how do you insert a word document object variable into a zip folder object in python (Note that this is not a word document that is already saved in my desktop)?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the **write** method combine with an **io.bytesIO stream** to add word file( with their format) to a ZIP archive object:

```
f = io.BytesIO()
zipObj = ZipFile(f, ‘a’)
for File_name in Obj_Attr_List:
    Contrat_word = Create_Word_Contract(File_name)
    Contrat_word.save(File_name + ‘.docx’)
    zipObj.write(File_name + ‘.docx’)
zipObj.close()
response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(),content_type=‘application/zip’)
response[‘Content-Disposition’] = ‘attachment; filename=ZipArchName.zip’
return response
```

PJ